# In Objective-C (or C), how does this code with pointer to a bool work?

Tags: c, objective-c, pointers, primitive

How does the `stop` mechanism work in this code?

```
@interface GifAnaimator()
@property BOOL stopping;
@end

@implementation GifAnaimator
- (void)startWithURL:(CFURLRef)imageURL {
    __weak GifAnaimator *weakSelf = self;
    CGAnimateImageAtURLWithBlock(imageURL, nil, ^(size_t index, CGImageRef image, bool* stop) {
        // Some image handling code...
        *stop = weakSelf.stopping;
    });
}

- (void)stop {
    self.stopping = YES;
}
@end
```

What's confusing me about this code is that the dereferenced `stop` is assigned a plain, non-pointed to, `BOOL`, `stopping`. Afterwards, when `stopping` is mutated, `stop` somehow gets the same mutation.

I tried capturing `stop` in a block, and calling the block later on to mutate it like so:

```objectivec
weakSelf.stopAnimation = ^{
   *stop = YES;
};
```

This code makes more sense to me but it doesn't work.

What exactly is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation comment for `CGAnimateImageAtURLWithBlock` says:

```
/* Animate the sequence of images contained in the file at `url'. Currently supported image
 * formats are GIF and APNG. The `options' dictionary may be used to request additional playback
 * options; see the list of keys above for more information. The block is called on the main queue
 * at time intervals specified by the `delay time' of the image. The animation can be stopped by
 * setting the boolean parameter of the block to false.
 */
```

If `self.stopping` is mutated and `*stop` later gets the same mutation I assume that's because the block is called after the value of `self.stopping` is changed and the block sets `*stop` to that value.

Capturing `*stop` won't work because in all likelihood it doesn't exist outside of the block.

`NSDictionary` has a method with a similar signature:

```
- (void)enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts 
                                usingBlock:(void (^)(KeyType key, ObjectType obj, BOOL *stop))block
```

In pseudo code this does something like:

```
for (key, object) in storage {
    BOOL stop = NO;
    block(key, object, &stop);
    if(stop) {
        break;
    }
}
```

So `stop` does not exist outside of the closure.

Comment: Got it thanks. I was thinking about it in the wrong way. That block runs over and over and keeps assigning to `*stop`. There’s no magical mutation happening on it.